# A database search alternative to Views

Tags: drupal, search, view

Is there an alternative module or way that I can query a drupal database to return results from a table for example, the users table, and have the search results visible even for anonymous users? I have tried using the views module but only a logged in user is able to see the results. I have changed the access permissions to no avail. I am working with Drupal 6. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason a view should only show up to logged out users, unless the data being loaded in the view is not available to logged out users. The view itself has permissions. Assuming you're in Views 3 (though 2 is similar) and depending whether it is a page or a block, the middle column will have "Block Settings" or "Page Settings" under which one of the options is "Access". You can tie the view to a specific permission, use custom PHP, or specifically enable it for certain roles. You can also choose "none" here and completely bypass permissions -- then the view will be available to everyone to see the data in, regardless of their permission to the data itself. However, be careful with that if there's any sensitive data on your site.

Views is definitely the best way to create an advanced search in Drupal. I'm sure there are alternatives, but this is exactly what Views is for, and Views is the #1 tool and #1 reason people use Drupal. What I recommend is opening a new issue for help figuring out why your view does not show to anonymous users.